# autocomplete text in all OSX's apps

Tags: macos, firefox, autocomplete

I find my self typing often certain words. And I remember there was a cool function in *Autohotkey* (for PC) that let you type only a few letters of a word and an autocomplete function, completed the word for you.

Is it possible to have the same thing in OSX?

The *Text Replacement* feature in OSX, doesn't work on every app (like *Firefox* for example where I needed it most)

I also tried with this line in the terminal:

```
defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true
```

but it did nothing.

at this point, even a *Firefox* addon will do.. 
(I found one called *MyWords* that was poorly developed though)

Thanks